# Visual Studio warning C4743: How does Whole Program Optimization affect _fltused?

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2005

So at work I'm working on a C++ application that runs without the C++ run-time library. We're using Visual Studio 2005, and have the /NODEFAULTLIB switch specified.

The solution is organized such that there are various static library projects, and then a single executable project which uses those libraries. The libraries are mostly common libraries tracked in a separate repository. They can be changed, but it's best for us not to, if we can avoid it.

One of those common libraries uses floating-point math. Since we don't have the C++ run-time, we have defined these routines ourself (ex: `_ftol2_sse` for converting float to int).

From my (rather limited) understanding of the low-level details, the compiler emits the symbol `_fltused` signal that floating point math routines need to be used.

For some reason, one of the other common libraries decides to define this symbol manually, as

```
extern "C" { unsigned short _fltused = 0; };
```

When I enable Whole Program Optimization and Link-time code generation, I get

```
warning C4743: '_fltused' has different size ...
```

when linking. I don't know why we have it declared as an `unsigned short` instead of `int`, but that's how it is.

When I don't enable Whole Program Optimization or LTCG, the warning goes away.

I guess I have two questions.

1. Can I safely ignore this warning?
2. What optimization is being made that causes the warning to occur? I'm not sure why it's not a warning without Whole Program Optimization enabled.

**UPDATE**

I was able to track down the original author of the code, who admits that it is a bug that occurred when rewriting the code from assembly language. He agrees with me that the warning is harmless, since `_fltused` is never actually used directly.

Answer (score 4):

I think I can answer 2 at least. It's not *any* specific optimization being made. It's the fact that whole program optimization forces the compiler to keep some representation of the whole program available to optimize from, and from that intermediate representation it's able to determine that the same variable has different sizes. When whole program optimization is not enabled the compiler only looks at each source file separately and doesn't see that two different files define different types for that symbol.

All that said I'm 99% sure your program violates the one definition rule, "undefined behavior, no diagnostic required". If you have *any* chance to fix it you should, against something as simple as a compiler patch breaking your code.

Comment: Good point about the one definition rule, but I'm not sure that's the case. If I comment out the library-provided definition of `_fltused` I get an unresolved external symbol error. Would that mean that only a declaration is being generated by the library that uses floating-point math, and that it declares the symbol as an `int`?

Comment: @njpaul: The One Definition Rule governs more than just definitions.

Comment: However, this particular case is a violation of 3.5 on linkage: " After all adjustments of types (during which typedefs (7.1.3) are replaced by their definitions), the types speciﬁed by all declarations referring to a given variable or function shall be identical, except that declarations for an array object can specify array types that differ by the presence or absence of a major array bound (8.3.4). A violation of this rule on type identity does not require a diagnostic." and not the one-definition rule